# Flutter Firebase Authentication : authStateChanges() method in StreamBuilder does not work in order to change from LoginScreen to Dashboard

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication, flutter-dependencies

I am using `StreamBuilder` inside the `home` property of `MaterialApp()` widget in the `main.dart` file in order to navigate between the WelcomeScreen (containing login and signup buttons)  and the DashboardScreen with the help of the `authStateChanges()` provided by `firebase_auth` package. But whenever I am logging in or signing up it stays on that screen only, until I manually Hot Reload the app. I have to hot reload the app in order to get from loginscreen to dashboard. The firebase auth is working correctly. I am able to see the user signed up in the firebase console. But the screen is not changing automatically. Also, there is no `Navigator.push()` method after the login or signup code.

main.dart:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

import 'package:banquet_owner_app/screens/welcome_screen.dart';
import 'package:banquet_owner_app/screens/dashboard.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: StreamBuilder(
        stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
        builder: (context, userSnapshot) {
          if (userSnapshot.hasData) {
            return Dashboard();
          }
          return WelcomeScreen();
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you need to get the state of the stream ,then check if it has data

here is how to go about it

```
home: StreamBuilder(
        stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
        builder: (context, userSnapshot) {
if (userSnapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
//loading screen
}
if (userSnapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
//state is loaded check if snapshot has data
if (userSnapshot.hasData) {
            return Dashboard();
          }else{
   return WelcomeScreen();
}
          
       
        },
```

Comment: I used your code but now its not able to change from WelcomeScreen to Dashboard even if Hot Reload. It stays on WelcomeScreen only.

Comment: i edited the code on SO directly must have misplaced a bracket.

Comment: I took care of the misplaced brackets. The code logic is not working. Also we have to return something in the builder, can't leave it blank.

Comment: did you ever resolve this? Facing a similar problem